# Define getter/setter methods with eval and __call in PHP

Tags: php, eval, setter, getter

The code I provide beliow is pointless, because I edited in a way it's easy to do tests with.

Btw in my case the ParentClass is the database class and the setter/getter methods are used to select and update table fields.

```
<?php

abstract class ParentClass {

    protected static
    $properties = []
    ;

    public function __construct() {
        foreach (static::$properties as $property) {
            $setterName = "Set".ucfirst($property);
            $this->$setterName = eval('function($value){$this->'.$property.' = $value;};');
            $getterName = "Get".ucfirst($property);
            $this->$getterName = eval('function(){return $this->'.$property.';};');
        }
    }

    public function __call($method, $args) {
        if (isset($this->$method)) {
            $func = $this->$method;
            return call_user_func_array($func, $args);
        }
    }

}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    protected static
    $properties = [
        "property1"
    ]
    ;

    protected
    $property1
    ;

}

$childClass = new ChildClass();
$childClass->SetProperty1("value");
echo $childClass->GetProperty1();

?>
```

The output of the script is nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? 5.4 added the array short syntax http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`eval`](http://php.net/eval) returns `NULL`, unless a `return` is somewhere in the `eval`ed code. Currently, when you set `$this->$setterName`, what your `eval` actually does is creates a closure, and then throws it away (because it's not otherwise used), returns `NULL`, and you wind up with `$this->SetProperty1 = NULL;`.

Instead, you should use the closures directly:

```
public function __construct() {
    foreach (static::$properties as $property) {
        $setterName = "Set".ucfirst($property);
        $this->$setterName = function($value) use($property) {$this->$property = $value;};
        $getterName = "Get".ucfirst($property);
        $this->$getterName = function() use($property) {return $this->$property;};
    }
}
```